# TortiseSVN 1.8 Slow over network

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server, network-share

I've been having this issue for some time now. Whenever trying to perform any action in TortoiseSVN on a directory under a mapped network drive the operation takes an inordinate amount of time to complete, while performing the same actions on my local drive are super fast.

I am unable to work on the files that I'm having the issue with on my local drive due to the development environment here.

Is there anything I can do (or get the sysadmin to do) to speed up the operations or will I just have to hurry up and wait?

TortoiseSVN 1.8.5, Build 25224 - 64 Bit , 2014/02/18 20:05:11
Subversion 1.8.8, -release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Don't use network drives!

TortoiseSVN is notoriously slow on network drives. This has to do with how it does those icon overlays. The speed issue on Network drives is mentioned in the manual in Chapter 4 about the settings. By default, TortoiseSVN turns off the overlays on network drives to help speed up network drive overlays. Do not turn it back on.

From the FAQ:

> **Why are the icons only visible on local and not on network drives?**
> Go to the `Settings -> Look and Feel -> Icon Overlays` and check the drive types for which you want to see overlay icons. Be aware that enabling overlays for network drives will slow down not only TortoiseSVN but the whole system.

I hope that you're not using `file://` protocol and and accessing the repo on a shared drive. [You are never supposed to do that](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-share).

Do not ever do use a shared repository over a network drive. There are several easy to install Windows based Subversion server packages (such as [VisualSVNServer](http://www.visualsvn.com) that are easy to setup and allow you to access SVN over a network. And, they are normally free.

You can even setup the `svnserve` lightweight Subversion service as a [Windows service](http://support.wandisco.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/162/15/running-svnserver-as-a-windows-service). Subversion is designed to be low maintenance and easy on the server. Any decent developer can easily setup a Subversion server and the repositories on that server. The [On line Subversion manual](http://svnbook.com) goes through various setups, and this is one of the best written technical manuals around.

In short: Don't use a network drive. There's simply no reason to. Your working copy should be local. If you must use a network drive (sometimes people's Home directory is a network share, and you're suppose to use all documents there), you may be forced to turn off icon overlays or use the Subversion command line (which TortoiseSVN comes with, and can be optionally installed).

Comment: Exclusive locking can help to solve the slow speed issue when WC is located on a network share: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#exclusivelocking

But the user has to be the only one who is accessing the WC.

Comment: A new feature. I wonder if TortoiseSVN can do that? Pre-1.7, it wasn't an issue. However, TortoiseSVN is slow on network drives because it has to do the overlays and cache them. On Network drives, maintaining those overlays can make Explorer painfully slow on Network drives which is why TortoiseSVN turns them off on network drives. However, it's hard using TSVN without them, so people turn them on, so they can use a network drive for a working copy.

Comment: nope it won't affect TortoiseSVN's status icons. The feature should be used with svn.exe command-line client which has to update a working copy stored on a share. There may be other cases I'm not aware of, though.